# Excel 2013: Sorting columns based on first row value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I would like to implement an Excel macro that sorts all columns from column "C" to the last column containing data (columns A and B shall not be affected).

The columns shall be sorted from A->Z based on the cell value of their first row (which is a string).

So far, I came up with the following code which I do not like that much because it contains hardcoded numbers for the Sort range making the code not really robust.

```
Sub SortAllColumns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Sort columns
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet").Sort
        .SetRange Range("C1:ZZ1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .Apply
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Searching the internet, one may find tons of suggestions getting the last used column or row. However most of them will blow up the code more than I expected.

I am not a VBA expert and it would be great if someone could make a suggestion how this problem can be solved in an elegant and efficient way.

If this is important: We will definitely not have more that 1000 rows and 1000 columns.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You mention start from column C, however, in the range you have specified start from column E? Which should it be?

Comment: `I do not like that much because it contains hardcoded numbers for the Sort range making the code not really robust.` You need to find the last row which has data and then construct your range `.SetRange Range("E1:ZZ" & LastRow)`. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) link on how to find the last row.

Comment: Similarly you can find the last column :)

Comment: @Janis S. You are right. That was a mistake in the sample code. Thanks!

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for your suggestion. I will have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions and revisions of @SiddharthRout I got this:

```
Sub SortAllColumns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim LastColumnLetter As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet")

    'Get range
    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastColumnLetter = Split(.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1)

       'Sort columns
        Range("C1:" & LastColumnLetter & LastRow).Select
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:" & LastColumnLetter & 1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        With .Sort
            .SetRange ws.Range("C1:" & LastColumnLetter & LastRow)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: my understanding of your question is that you need to sort columns by moving them so as to have their headers sorted from left to right. if that's true then your code isn't doing that

Comment: @user3598756 I made my question more clear. No I did not want to move the columns. My goal was to sort the columns but with and expanded selection so that the row values of each column are considered as well.

Comment: then you'd better remove " the whole column shall be moved " from your question

Answer (score 1):

**edited:**

- changed temporary sheet adding statement to have it always as the last one
- revised its deletion statement accordingly

should your need be to sort columns by moving them so as to have their headers sorted from left to right, then try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim lastCol As Long

With Sheets("mySheet")
    lastCol = .cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Call OrderColumns(Range(.Columns(3), Columns(lastCol)))
End With

End Sub


Sub OrderColumns(columnsRng As Range)
Dim LastRow As Long

With columnsRng
    LastRow = GetColumnsLastRow(columnsRng)
    With .Resize(LastRow)
        .Copy

        With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).cells(1, 1).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count) 'this will add a "helper" sheet: it'll be removed
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
            .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo 
            .Copy
        End With
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Delete: Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'remove the "helper" sheet (it's the (n-1)th sheet)

    End With

End With

End Sub


Function GetColumnsLastRow(rng As Range) As Long
Dim i As Long
'gets last row of the given columns range

GetColumnsLastRow = -1
With rng
    For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
        GetColumnsLastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(GetColumnsLastRow, .Parent.cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Columns(i).Column).End(xlUp).row)
    Next i
End With
End Function
```

it makes use of a "helper" temporary (it gets deleted by the end) sheet.

Comment: Very nice answer. If columns need to be moved, this seems to be the way to go.